# How to Compare two columns of one csv file with another in VBScript

Tags: regex, csv, dictionary, vbscript

I have two csv files one with four columns and another with four columns, for eg

```
File 1                     File 2
ID,Contry,state,amt        ID,Contry,state,amt 
1,US,01,7                  13,AU,0,7 
2,UK,11,7                  11,UK,0,7 
3,AF,10,7                  10,AF,0,7 
4,US,08,7                  14,SG,0,7
```

I need two compare the second two columns of file 1 with the first two coulmns of file2 and remove the duplicates of matched rows in file2 using vbscript. for eg the output needs to be

```
file3
ID,Contry,state,amt 
13,AU,0,7
14,SG,0,7
```

Sample codes will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to work with .CSV is to use ADO/Text Drivers (cf [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17056504/603855)). If the data are funny, or specs are too vague for nice SQL statements (or you never used SQL before), a hack involving the FileSystemObject, string ops, and a Dictionary to store the distinct values in the first file's second column may be acceptable:

```
  Dim oFS   : Set oFS   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim dicC  : Set dicC  = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim tsOut : Set tsOut = oFS.CreateTextFile("..\data\25909493-3.txt")
  Dim tsIn
  Set tsIn = oFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\25909493-1.txt")
  tsOut.WriteLine tsIn.ReadLine() ' header
  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
     dicC(Split(tsIn.ReadLine(), ",")(1)) = 0 ' col 2 into dicC.Keys
  Loop
  tsIn.Close
  WScript.Echo "to filter:", Join(dicC.Keys(), ", ")
  Set tsIn = oFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\25909493-2.txt")
  tsIn.ReadLine
  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
     Dim sLine : sLine = tsIn.ReadLine()
     If Not dicC.Exists(Split(sLine, ",")(1)) Then
        tsOut.WriteLine sLine
     End If
  Loop
  tsIn.Close
  tsOut.Close
  WScript.Echo "..\data\25909493-3.txt:"
  WScript.Echo oFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\25909493-3.txt").ReadAll()
```

output:

```
to filter: US, UK, AF
..\data\25909493-3.txt:
ID,Contry,state,amt
13,AU,0,7
14,SG,0,7
```